# POST method not getting any response code in Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have created simple app to load the file on the local path. I noticed that I am not getting any response code after submitted 'Upload' option. How do I need to get the successful response code 200.

**app.js**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const http = require("http").Server(app).listen(3000);
    const upload = require("express-fileupload");
    const dialog = require("dialog");

    app.use(upload());

    console.log("Server Started");

    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    }
    )

    app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    if (req.files) {
        //console.log(req.files);
        const file = req.files.filename;
        const filename = file.name;

        console.log(req.body.test_text);

        file.mv("./upload/" + filename, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send("error occured");
        }
        else {
            //res.send('ok');
            // dialog.info("loaded");
            console.log("loaded")
        }
        })
    }
    })
```

**index.html**

```
    <div>
    <h1 style="align-content: center">Upload your file here!</h1>
    </div>
    <div style=" background-color: white;
                padding:64px;
                display:flex;
                align-items:flex-start;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                box-shadow:  0 15px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11), 0 20px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
                box-sizing:border-box">

    <form label="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        <label> Enter reference</label>
        <input type="text" name="test_text"></input>
        <br><br>
        <input type="file" name="filename">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
    </div>
```

If you see below screenshot, the file got uploaded to the local path. However, I am not getting any successful response code to end the transaction.

[image]

Comment: Just a FYI, you can use `res.status(400);` to indicate error or `res.status(200);` to indicate success prior to call `res.send('Some message here');`

Comment: Two things: **1)** `//res.send('ok');` If file.mv() succeeds, you do not send a response, since this part is commented out. **2)** `In Express 4, req.files is no longer available on the req object by default. To access uploaded files on the req.files object, use multipart-handling middleware`. So if you use Express v4 or newer, you don not have access to `req.files` anymore as written and since there's no else clause to `if (req.files) {`, you also do not send a response. Refer to the Express docs for more information.

Comment: @acarlstein - Yes, it works. But i just want to get the success status and keep on the same page. If I use res.send(''), then it redirecting to another page

Comment: @acarlstein Thanks, for your help!

Comment: @Nandy don't forget to vote ;)

Comment: @Nandy, why not re-render the same html page in your post route. It's the simplest i could think

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar, I did the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely because `req.files` is not defined. just add another condition that says: If `req.files` doesn't exist, return a response.

Comment: I am using html form with enctype = "multipart/form-data" , i thought it would define the files.

Comment: `req.files` does not exist by default in express, you have to have middleware to parse that from the request and add `files` onto the `req` object.. that is what `express-fileupload` should be doing for you. Idk why its not defined, but add the condition to check if it doesnt exist and return a response... thatll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems req.files is not defined or Some error is thrown in if condition, always use try catch to handle this kind of situation and use else as well.

To access req.files, you use multer, busboy a npm modules, which will help you in uploading larger files as well.